# rowcommand in dynamically created gridviews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, postback

I've got serious gridview trouble.
The rowcommand in my dynamically created gridview isn't firing.

```
            Controls_ucOffice userControl = (Controls_ucOffice)LoadControl("~/Controls/ucOffice.ascx");
            userControl.ID = *Unique ID*

            GridView gvPhones =(GridView) userControl.FindControl("myGridView");
            gvPhones.DataSource = cPhoneList;
            gvPhones.DataBind();

            placeholder1.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

i'm making several of these controls, and they all appear fine with the gridviews, with the right data. 
this is done on a button click and not on page_load.

i know they dissappear on postback so i've placed them in update panels, to avoid losing the gridviews (populating them takes quite a while)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPhones" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvPhones_RowDataBound"
            OnRowCommand="gvPhones_RowCommand">
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPhones" EventName="RowCommand" />
</Triggers>
```

after putting them in the update panel, at first click nothing happens, second click makes all the gridviews dissappear (as in there was a postback)

the breakpoint in the rowcommand method below is never reached

```
protected void gvPhones_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the UpdatePanels?

Comment: the gridviews dissappear after a single click, which i assume is because of the postback.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, why does it have to work without updatepanels?

Comment: If it doesn't work without updatepanels, there are few chances to work with them. The control tree must be built every time, on every postback. This is the main problem with dynamic controls, to build every time the tree.

Comment: I see, I've come to use a solution where i use hyperlinks in the gridview and then callt he site with url parameters. It works, but it's not very elegant imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding the grid in page load like below

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    BindGrid();
}
```

then get the BindGrid() out of !IsPostBack. Means you need to Rebind() the grid on every postback if you are creating the grid on runtime.